# How to use RESTEasy PreProcessInterceptor only in specific methods?

Tags: java, rest, resteasy, interceptor

I'm writing a REST API, making use of RestEasy 2.3.4.Final.
I know that a Interceptor will intercept all of my requests, and that a PreProcessInterceptor will be the first (before everything) to be called. I would like to know how can I make this Interceptor to be called just when specific methods are called.

I tried to use both PreProcessInterceptor and AcceptedByMethod, but I was not able to read the parameters I need.
For example, I need to run my Interceptor only when this method is called:

```
@GET
@Produces("application/json;charset=UTF8")
@Interceptors(MyInterceptor.class)
public List<City> listByName(@QueryParam("name") String name) {...}
```

To be more specific, I need to run my Interceptor in all methods whose have a `@QueryParam("name")`

on its signature, so that I can grab the name and do something before everything.

Is it possible? I tried to catch the "name" parameter inside the Interceptor, but I was not able to do that.

Could someone help me, please?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `AcceptedByMethod` as explained in the [RESTEasy documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/2.3.4.Final/userguide/html_single/index.html#BindingInterceptors)

Create a class that implement both `PreProcessInterceptor` and `AcceptedByMethod`. In the `accept`-method, you can check if the method has a parameter with annotated with `@QueryParam("name")`. If the method has that annotation, return true from the `accept`-method.

In the `preProcess`-method, you can get the query parameter from `request.getUri().getQueryParameters().getFirst("name")`.

**EDIT:**

Here is an example:

```
public class InterceptorTest  {

    @Path("/")
    public static class MyService {

        @GET
        public String listByName(@QueryParam("name") String name){
            return "not-intercepted-" + name;
        }
    }

    public static class MyInterceptor implements PreProcessInterceptor, AcceptedByMethod {

        @Override
        public boolean accept(Class declaring, Method method) {
            for (Annotation[] annotations : method.getParameterAnnotations()) {
                for (Annotation annotation : annotations) {
                    if(annotation.annotationType() == QueryParam.class){
                        QueryParam queryParam = (QueryParam) annotation;
                        return queryParam.value().equals("name");
                    }
                }
            }
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public ServerResponse preProcess(HttpRequest request, ResourceMethod method)
                throws Failure, WebApplicationException {

            String responseText = "intercepted-" + request.getUri().getQueryParameters().getFirst("name");
            return new ServerResponse(responseText, 200, new Headers<Object>());
        }
    }

    @Test
    public void test() throws Exception {
        Dispatcher dispatcher = MockDispatcherFactory.createDispatcher();
        dispatcher.getProviderFactory().getServerPreProcessInterceptorRegistry().register(new MyInterceptor());
        dispatcher.getRegistry().addSingletonResource(new MyService());

        MockHttpRequest request = MockHttpRequest.get("/?name=xxx");
        MockHttpResponse response = new MockHttpResponse();

        dispatcher.invoke(request, response);

        assertEquals("intercepted-xxx", response.getContentAsString());
    }
}
```

Comment: Thankyou @eiden. I tryed this before, but without using the `@Context`. But, when I try to retrieve some data from the injected context, it throws an Exception because the context was not initialized I guess.
    
org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/api]] (MSC service thread 1-3) Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ResteasyBootstrap: org.jboss.resteasy.spi.LoggableFailure: Unable to find contextual data of type: javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest

Comment: I don't know why you are using @Context? Anyways, I've updated my answer with a code example

Comment: Excelent @eiden. I almost got it working that way, but i did not realized `if(annotation.annotationType() == QueryParam.class){
                        QueryParam queryParam = (QueryParam) annotation;
                        return queryParam.value().equals("name");`
Many Thanks for helping me! 
And I hope it helps some more people.

Comment: You're welcome! `annotation.annotationType()` is a classic java 'gotcha' :)

Answer (score 2):

if you return `return new ServerResponse(responseText, 200, new Headers<Object>());` you will lose the end-point. you need to return `null` if you still want the message to be delivered to the final point.